# Issue during the use of list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the below python code that should be checking if the value of a parameter in cfg has the correct value that can be find in the dictionary dict_methos_modes, see below:

So if the tmp_method is 'rough' then the parameter mode (from the cfg file) should have only one of the values: 'per_node', 'master_only', 'slave_only', 'master_slave'. If the parameter mode has different value the code should remove the option and in a next step add the default one!

```
listSectionsInCfg = ['Settings', 'Run']
listSettingsParameters = ['method', 'mode']
listExecutionParameters = ['test']

dict_methods_modes = {
'rough':['per_node', 'master_only', 'slave_only', 'master_slave'],
'medium':['replica', 'master', 'slave']}

cfg = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
cfg.optionxform = str
cfg.read(file)
try:
    for section in listSectionsCfg:
        print 'Now reading %s'%(section)
        assert cfg.has_section(section)
        if section == 'Settings': listCandidate = listSettingsParameters
        if section == 'Run': listCandidate = listExecutionParameters
        for candidate in listCandidate:
            if 'method' == candidate:
                if cfg.has_option(section, candidate):
                    tmp_method = cfg.get(section, candidate)
                    if all(x != tmp_method for x in dict_methods_modes):
                        print '%s.%-12s  : %s -> wrong syntax, cleared'%(section, candidate, tmp_method)
                        cfg.remove_option(section, candidate)
            elif 'mode' == candidate:
                tmp_method = cfg.get(section, 'method')
                if cfg.has_option(section, candidate):
                    tmp_mode = cfg.get(section, candidate)
                    print 'TEST-POINT:%s.%-12s  : %s'%(section, candidate, tmp_mode)
                    ll = [v for v in dict_methods_modes[tmp_method] if v == tmp_mode]
                    print 'TEST-POINT:%s'%(ll)
                    if not ll:
                        print '%s.%-12s  : %s -> wrong syntax, cleared'%(section, candidate, tmp_mode)
                        cfg.remove_option(section, candidate)
            # Check if candidate exists
            if cfg.has_option(section, candidate):
                continue
            else: # if not set default values for candidate
                print '%s.%-12s  : %s -> missing'%(section, candidate, cfg.has_option(section, candidate))
                if 'method' == candidate:
                    cfg.set(section, candidate, 'rough')
                    print '%s.%-12s  : %s'%(section, candidate, cfg.get(section, candidate))
                elif 'mode' == candidate:
                    cfg.set(section, candidate, 'per_node')
                    print '%s.%-12s  : %s'%(section, candidate, cfg.get(section, candidate))
```

if i execute the above code i get the below printout the parameter mode in the cfg file is set to 'blabla',

cfg file:

```
[Settings]
method = rough
mode = blabla
[Run]
test = once
```

but i am getting:

```
TEST-POINT:Settings.mode  : per_node
TEST-POINT:['per_node']
```

Since ll is not empty it will not remove the mode parameter to get at the next step the default value!

Another thing is that if i remark out the if-statement for checking the list ll empty:

```
        #if not ll:
        #    print '%s.%-12s  : %s -> wrong syntax, cleared'%(section, candidate, tmp_mode)
        #    cfg.remove_option(section, candidate)
```

The printout in this case is:

```
TEST-POINT:Settings.mode  : blabla
TEST-POINT:[]
```

Which is correct, but the code can't remove the mode parameter!
What am i doing wrong in my code?

Comment: I just ran the code you posted (with minor modifications so that it would run) and it gave the correct output, so I'm not sure why this isn't working for you.

Comment: I added some more code, but in my case i still see the same observation when i have the if-statement active!